# Navigation is... Timid

Tags: ros, navigation, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble with navigation. The robot moves in little jerks, not in fluid motion... What parameters should I look at for this?

Also,

I'm getting warnings from the map update timing. How do I make these go away? It is trying to update it too quickly, and it may be the orgin of the problem. The robot is connected to a master over wifi. Here, the master runs the navigation while the robot runs the sensors and motors (not much of a processor on the robot). Could this be the start of the delay?

Thanks in advance,

-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38109/navigation-is...-timid/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

for mapping update timing, you can change update_frequency in global_costmap_params.yaml and local_costmap_params.yaml and you may consider lowering the publish_frequency because of computational load.

about your motion, you may decrease your acceleration parameters, and make you sure that your robot is following cmd_vel 's datas corretly, record your velocity params and record cmd_vel then plot them in rxgraph, see if given velocity datas and your velocities match

for more and detailed information check navigation tunining wiki

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1